# linear algebra. matrix of transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the transformation $T:P_2→P_2$, where $P_2$ is the space of second-degree polynomials matrices, given by $T(f)=f(−1)+f′(−1)(t+1)$. Find the matrix for this transformation relative to the standard basis $\mathfrak{A}=\{1,t,t^2\}$.
can someone explain to me how to find the matrix of the transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example: our third basis vector is $t^2$.  We find that
$$
T(t^2) = (-1)^2 + 2(-1) \cdot (t+1) = (-1)1 + (-2)t + (0)t^2
$$
we therefore find that the third column of our matrix is $(-1,-2,0)$.  Proceed in a like fashion for the remaining columns.

Comment: oh i got it! thank you!